# Null Reference Exception when writing to an array. c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am simply trying to write months to an array in a certain order.

```
                                string January = "January";
                                string February = "February";
                                string March = "March";
                                string April = "April";
                                string May = "May";
                                string June = "June";
                                string July = "July";
                                string August = "August";
                                string September = "September";
                                string October = "October";
                                string November = "November";
                                string December = "December";
```

and then writing to the array like so:

```
                            for (int i = 0; i < (janC - 1); i++)
                                {
                                    analyser.sortedmonths[i] = January;
                                }
```

sortedmonths is initialized in another cs sheet.
The sorted months array is 1022 in size as that is the amount of months being read in.

Why is this not working? I have googled the null reference exception but have not found anything related to writing to an array.

Comment: probably you need `analyser.sortedmonths = new string[12];`

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca I have string[] sortedmonths; already setup

Comment: maybe `analyser` is null.

Answer (score 0):

`analyzer.sortedmonths` is null. You have to initialize it:

```
analyzer.sortedmonths = new string[12];
```

Comment: I have 1022 months being read in, i am counting how many there are of each months, then rebuilding the array in calendar order. I have initialized this string array.